# probability distribution of balls in an urn

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So I have the following question in "probability":

An urn contains three balls: white, blue and red. At each stage a ball is
picked up randomly and, if it is not red, it is returned to the urn. The
process is repeated until the first time the red ball is picked up. Then
the process ends. Denote by: $X$ the number of times the blue ball was
chosen; $Y$ the number of times the white ball was chosen; and $L$ the
length of the process. For example, if the blue ball was chosen the first three times, the fourth time the white ball was chosen, and the fifth time the red, then $X = 3$; $Y = 1$; $L = 5$.

I need to fine $E(Y)$, but it's not the problem. I'm having troubles in finding the Probability distribution of $Y$.

I would be grateful if someone could give me a hint or an explanation on how to calculate $P(Y=k)$ for each $k=1,2,\ldots$

Please, I don't want the answer, just a hint!

Comment: It could be useful to leave a comment after downvoting so that the new user might learn how to make a better question.

Comment: Hint #1: If you just care about $Y$, then each time you draw a blue ball, you can consider that draw to be a "do-over", i.e., ignore what happened and act as if no ball had been drawn. This affects $L$ but can you see what effect it will have on $Y$?

Comment: Hint #2: A usual approach to a problem like this is _not_ to compute the distribution of $Y$ at all (so ignore Hint #1) but instead set up an equation involving $EY$ and solve it. You can set up such an equation by considering just two things: what happens when you draw the first ball, and what you can "expect" to happen during all subsequent draws up to the end of the game.